# Eslint react-hooks/exhaustive derps recursion

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

I need some help wrapping my head around `eslint` `react-hooks/exhaustive derps`.
I ONLY want the effect to run when `listenToMe` has changed, but `react-hooks/exhaustive derps` is yelling at me to add `history`. This causes recursion. `useEffect` was React gold for me until this rule.

> ESLint: React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'history'. Either include them or remove the dependency array.(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)

Can someone help me understand:

1. Why is it bad practice to only listen for changes you care about in useEffect?
2. What is the "right" way to only listen for specific changes on state change?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (listenToMe) {
        const search = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
        search.delete('q')
        history.replace({ ...location, search: search.toString() });
      }
    }
  }, [listenToMe]);
```

I've read through github and react, but I haven't read anything that clicks.

- https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6880
- https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html
- Many others...

Comment: React's explanation  https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#what-can-i-do-if-my-effect-dependencies-change-too-often

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs

> It is only safe to omit a function from the dependency list if nothing in it (or the functions called by it) references props, state, or values derived from them.

The problem arises when you're using passed props or in your case, the history prop coming from a HOC or hook from react-router.

First of all, its passed as a prop, and props can inherently change.

Second of all, you're calling a history.push function. The linter doesn't know that push will always be the same function of the history class and that this function will not use any state or props itself.

The "right" way according to facebook is to move the function inside the effect, but that doesn't make sense if you're just reusing code from some file or using a function like history.push. So I think in your case the solution would be to wrap it in a useCallback with history in its own dependancy array. This is a last resort according to the devs.

Essentially, useCallback will simply return a memoized value instead of actually accessing the value and whenever the value in it's dependancy changes, there is a new callback with new memoized values.

History.push will of course always have the same identity so this somewhat of an anti-pattern.

Personally I have never had any problems passing in values like this. So I think writing a useCallback when you're just dealing with functions declared elsewhere (or any fully stable variable) is pointless and I find it reasonable to skip linting that line.

I keep the rule enabled as others have pointed out however, as its good to keep you on your toes about writing effects.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation. This helps a lot!!

Comment: @boy The question was about useEffect, not useCallback. I think it's perfectly fine to listen to only subset of variable changes in useEffect (if that's your intent).

Answer (score 0):

This eslint rule is only a hint useful in *most* situations, but in some situations you have to ignore it.

```
React.useEffect(()=> {

  // I have some code with dependencies here but I only want to run it on mount

// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [])
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I just want to wrap my head around WHY it's a rule. VS Code and IntelliJ auto "fix" this error by auto adding the dependancies. Causes way more harm than good IMO. Adding /* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
to the page prevents this, but I FEEL SO DIRTY adding validation skips ha! I would prefer to understand rather than ignorantly ignore the rule.

Comment: I would rather add the rule to each useEffect than disabling it globally, because this rule is still useful to prevent mistakes. I was confused at first too because it seems like bad practice to go against a linting rule but imo this one needs to overridden sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

React disabled the auto fixer
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15204

I installed the new `devDependancies` (`eslint@latest` and `eslint-plugin-react-hooks`)

```
npm install eslint@latest eslint-plugin-react-hooks@latest --save-dev
```

I tested in IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 (EAP Build #IU-201.5985.32) and it **shows the warning**, but `ESLint Fix` **does not auto add dependancies**  to `useEffect`

> **ESLint Warning in IntelliJ**
>
> ESLint: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dispatch'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. If 'dispatch' changes too often, find the parent component that defines it and wrap that definition in useCallback.(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)

VS Code has the "fix" in pre release `2.1.0-next.1`, but I have not tested it.

> https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/pull/814#issuecomment-587020489
> https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/releases/tag/release%2F2.1.0-next.1

This does NOT answer the question, but helpfull to anyone who runs into `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` auto "fix" issues.